# How to select elements having more than one attribute values?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the [validationEngine plugin](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) there is the class `validate` which may have many arguments inside : for example `validate[required,custom[email]]`. In my css file I want to select elements having class `validate` containing `required`. The keyword `required` may be placed anywhere inside the `[]` of the `validate` keyword. How to make the selection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `validate[required,custom[email]]`

Ouch. Talk about a poorly designed class attribute.

The best you can do here is match both keywords "validate" and "required" in the class attribute. Depending on the plugin, this may be enough for you:

```
input[class*="validate"][class*="required"]
```

You cannot use class selectors here because the entire class attribute value counts as a single class name, meaning the *only* class selector that would match that class name is `.validate\[required\,custom\[email\]\]` (which is why that class attribute is the epitome of poor design).

Answer (score 3):

This link might come in handy for you: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I believe you'll want something along the lines of:

```css
.input[class*="required"]
{
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: That won't work because there are no spaces in the attribute value. The only ~= attribute selector that will match the element is [class~="validate[required,custom[email]]"] (yes, the whole shebang).

Comment: Good spot. I was just trying this locally on my machine. It appears that [class*="required"] works. I've edited the answer respectively.